# Ignorando pasta do git dentro do repositório

Tags: git

Como faço para ignorar pastas .git/ e .gitignore dentro do meu projeto?

Estou tendo problemas ao clonar vendors externo no meu projeto por causa disso, toda vez que eu clono/baixo alguma dependência com o composer ele vem com a pasta do git e ao comitar as alterações a pasta que contém o .git/ não envia e nem adciona no **git add --all**

Comment: coloque ela dentro do .gitignore

Comment: A pasta "vendor" sempre será ignorada mesmo, pois ela é individual.  Pois para cada aplicação o composer realizará o download de todas suas dependências individualmente, ou seja, se você possuir 3 aplicações, o composer.phar será somente 1, no entanto os vendors serão específicos para cada projeto.

Comment: Dá uma lida aqui, pode te ajudar: http://tableless.com.br/composer-um-pouco-alem-basico/

Comment: Aqui na empresa estão usando um CMS que instala com um php e não vem composer.json.

Comment: Para você poder versionar o diretório `vendor` você tem que habilitar isso pelo composer. `"config": { "vendor-dir": "3rdparty" }`

Comment: Então o jeito é arrastar mesmo. No seu caso.

Comment: Mas estranho, porque se você clona uma dependência com o composer, eu imagino que exista o composer.json

Comment: git add --all, ou git add . ? git add --all é para remover tudo não?

Comment: Nas dependências existe os json, a minha aplicação que não existe, entendem?

Answer (score 2):

Em vários gerenciadores de dependências, é uma boa prática não incluir os arquivos baixados pelo gerenciador dentro de seu repositório, sempre sendo baixados através do gerenciador. Se for dessa forma, adicione as pastas/arquivos do gerenciador ao `.gitignore`.

Se você preferir baixar outros repositórios dentro do seu, você pode usar submódulos.

Para adicionar um submódulo ao seu projeto use:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
```

Onde a URL será do repositório que você está baixando.

Ao clonar um repositório com submódulos, eles virão vazios por padrão. Para baixá-los, use:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Assim você atualizará as configurações e baixará o repositório do submódulo.

Comment: Olá Erick, podes dar algum exemplo do link que colocaste. Senão caso esse link se parta um dia, a resposta fica invalidada.

Comment: Editado. Removi o link e incluí os comandos básicos na resposta.